# Synchronization \ backup of directories and files (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, thread-safety, windows

stackexchange members. I'm just learning to write. I set myself a task a few days ago and today I completed its implementation. The task was to create a "backupper" (I was inspired just by my homework with "Byte of Python"): you specify from where and where the synchronization of all content will go. After that there is synchronization (copying, replacing and, if necessary, deleting). I would like to bring you my decision to defeat. As for me, it turned out, as for such a simple task, quite cumbersome. If anyone has any ideas for improving the code - making it more logical, elegant, and stripping away all the frills - I would be extremely grateful for any ideas and solutions! I apologize in advance for the stupidity.

```
#it took too much
import os
from dirsync import sync
import json
from pathlib import Path
import shutil 

#block access to "memory"
print('\nHere are your backup paths ("Name":"From where we make backup">>>"Where we make backup"):\n')
with open('left.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as lreadmemory: 
    lmemory = json.load(lreadmemory) 
    for name in lmemory: 
        for n,l in name.items(): 
            #print(n, ':', l) 
            with open('right.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rreadmemory:
                rmemory = json.load(rreadmemory)  
                for name2 in rmemory:  
                    for a, b in name2.items():
                        if a==n: 
                            print('   ',n, ':', '"', l, '"', '>>>', '"', b, '"')  

while True:
    filename = input('\n\n\You can enter the name of your old backup path, if you need new backups - enter "new"::')

## block for writing new values to memory
    if filename == 'new':
        while True:
            newwayname = input('\Name:')
            if newwayname == 'new':
                print('Not "new"') # ingenious solution (not really)
            else:
                break
        while True:
            newwayfrom = input('From where we make backup:')
            if os.path.isdir(newwayfrom) == True:
                break
            else:
                print('Not dir')
        while True:
            newwayto = input('Where we make backup:')
            if os.path.isdir(newwayto) == True:
                break
            else:
                print('Not dir')

        jsleft = {}
        jsright = {}

        jsleft[newwayname] = newwayfrom 
        jsright[newwayname] = newwayto

        jleft = json.load(open('left.json', encoding='utf-8'))  
        jleft.append(jsleft)  
        json.dump(jleft, open('left.json', 'w'),indent=4)  

        jleft = json.load(open('right.json', encoding='utf-8'))
        jleft.append(jsright)
        json.dump(jleft, open('right.json', 'w'), indent=4)

#call-by-name block
        while True:
            hisname = input('\nEnter the name of the backup path you want to execute:')

            with open('left.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as leftreadmemory:
                memory_l = json.load(leftreadmemory)  
                for name_l in memory_l:  
                    for al, bl in name_l.items():  
                        if al == hisname:
                            left_way = bl
                            break
            with open('right.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rightreadmemory:
                memory_r = json.load(rightreadmemory)  
                for name_r in memory_r:  
                    for ar, br in name_r.items():  
                        if ar == hisname:
                            right_way = br
                            break
            break

        while True:
            copyornot = input('Copy? (Y/n):')
            if copyornot == 'Y':
                break
            elif copyornot == 'n':
                print('...')
                continue
            else:
                print('(Y/n)')

#copy block
        while True:
            try:
                sync(left_way, right_way, 'sync')  
                break
            except NameError:
                print('Invalid name specified')
                break
#call-by-name block
    else:
        hisname = filename
        while True:
            with open('left.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as leftreadmemory:
                memory_l = json.load(leftreadmemory)  
                for name_l in memory_l:  
                    for al, bl in name_l.items():  
                        if al == hisname:
                            left_way = bl
                            break
            with open('right.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as rightreadmemory:
                memory_r = json.load
                for name_r in memory_r:  
                    for ar, br in name_r.items():  
                        if ar == hisname:
                            right_way = br
                            break
            break

        while True:
            copyornot = input('Copy? (Y/n):')
            if copyornot == 'Y':
                break
            elif copyornot == 'n':
                print('...')
                continue
            else:
                print('(Y/n)')
#copy block
        while True:
            try:
                sync(left_way, right_way, 'sync')  
                break
            except NameError:
                print('invalid name specified')
                break

# "excess" removal block for the right side

        pl = Path(left_way)
        pr = Path(right_way)

        difference = (set(map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pr), pr.rglob('*'))) - set(
            map(lambda p: p.relative_to(pl), pl.rglob('*'))))

        if len(difference) > 0:
            print('\nExcess:\n')
            for a in difference:
                a2 = Path(pr, a)
                print('   ', a2)
            while True:
                copyornot = input('\nRemove? (Y/n):\n')
                if copyornot == 'Y':
                    break
                elif copyornot == 'n':
                    print('...') 
                    continue
                else:
                    print('(Y/n)')
            for a in difference:
                a2 = Path(pr, a)
                if os.path.isfile(a2):
                    os.remove(a2)
                if os.path.isdir(a2):
                    shutil.rmtree(a2)
            print('\nI has worked conscientiously, now I can drink beer with a pure soul')
```

I hope all is well with you by this moment... One way or another, I look forward to any criticism, comments, ideas in the comments.

Example 'left.json'

```
[
    {
        "1": "C:\\From_here"
    }
]
```

Example 'right.json'

```
[
    {
        "1": "C:\\To_here"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please show the contents of sample left and right JSON files.

Comment: Added initial version. Then the lists are replenished by the user.

Answer (score -2):

while true is ok but you may consider while_running == True
then have a input at the end to cancel in y eyes have break for any reason could cause unexpected things